# Kafka Streams calculations app - most efficient way to account for time elapsed in streams app

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have Kafka Streaming API application joining 2 streams which works ok.

I have another Kafka Streaming API application which is performing some calculations based on joined values from 1st application - also works ok.

Results of calculations are used to trigger commands on PLC server.

Messages are coming in every 25ms which is window for join in 1st application.
Now I have requirement which says after each trigger wait for xy milliseconds before allowing next trigger on PLC server.
So Kafka Streams should continue to process messages and not trigger PLC and after some time it should allow triggering of PLC server.

I'm puzzled on how to implement that in most efficient way since speed is most important here - I need to account for elapsed time in some global variable outside of stream scope and than when each message arrives probably check against this variable to find out how much time elapsed.

It's pretty straightforward I'm only thinking if there is any other more suitable and faster way of doing this?

Here is code of my current calculations application:

```
package io.confluent.developer;

import io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClient;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.NewTopic;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.*;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Produced;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Printed;
import pmu.serialization.avro.pmujoinedrule_voltageall;
import pmu.serialization.avro.pmujoinstream;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;


public class JoinWithRule_VoltageAll {

    public Topology buildTopology(Properties allProps) {
        final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        final String pmuJoinStreamTopic = allProps.getProperty("output.topic.name");
        final String rulesTopic = allProps.getProperty("rules.topic.name");

        KStream<String, pmujoinstream> pmuJoinStream = builder.stream(pmuJoinStreamTopic);
        KStream<String, pmujoinedrule_voltageall> pmuJoinedRule = pmuJoinStream.map((key, pmujoinstream) -> {
            try {
                return new KeyValue<>(pmujoinstream.getTimeRounded214(), calculateAngleDiff(pmujoinstream));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });
        pmuJoinedRule.to(rulesTopic, Produced.with(Serdes.String(),pmuJoinRuleAvroSerde(allProps)));
        return builder.build();
    }

    public static pmujoinedrule_voltageall calculateAngleDiff(pmujoinstream pmuJoinedStream) throws IOException {
        // faza R, PMU1
        double angle_V_R_PMU1;
        double V_R_param1_PMU1 = pmuJoinedStream.getPhV4R214();
        double V_R_param2_PMU1 = pmuJoinedStream.getPhV4J214();

        // faza R, PMU2
        double angle_V_R_PMU2;
        double V_R_param1_PMU2 = pmuJoinedStream.getPhV4R218();
        double V_R_param2_PMU2 = pmuJoinedStream.getPhV4J218();

        // faza S, PMU1
        double angle_V_S_PMU1;
        double V_S_param1_PMU1 = pmuJoinedStream.getPhV5R214();
        double V_S_param2_PMU1 = pmuJoinedStream.getPhV5J214();

        // faza S, PMU2
        double angle_V_S_PMU2;
        double V_S_param1_PMU2 = pmuJoinedStream.getPhV5R218();
        double V_S_param2_PMU2 = pmuJoinedStream.getPhV5J218();

        // faza T, PMU1
        double angle_V_T_PMU1;
        double V_T_param1_PMU1 = pmuJoinedStream.getPhV6R214();
        double V_T_param2_PMU1 = pmuJoinedStream.getPhV6J214();

        // faza T, PMU2
        double angle_V_T_PMU2;
        double V_T_param1_PMU2 = pmuJoinedStream.getPhV6R218();
        double V_T_param2_PMU2 = pmuJoinedStream.getPhV6J218();

        // promijeniti u true ako imamo podatke u kartezijevom obliku
        boolean cartesian = false;

        if (cartesian) {
            // ako podaci dolaze u kartezijevom obliku param1 je X, param2 je Y
            angle_V_R_PMU1 = calcAngleDegFromCartesian(V_R_param1_PMU1, V_R_param2_PMU1);
            angle_V_R_PMU2 = calcAngleDegFromCartesian(V_R_param1_PMU2, V_R_param2_PMU2);
            angle_V_S_PMU1 = calcAngleDegFromCartesian(V_S_param1_PMU1, V_S_param2_PMU1);
            angle_V_S_PMU2 = calcAngleDegFromCartesian(V_S_param1_PMU2, V_S_param2_PMU2);
            angle_V_T_PMU1 = calcAngleDegFromCartesian(V_T_param1_PMU1, V_T_param2_PMU1);
            angle_V_T_PMU2 = calcAngleDegFromCartesian(V_T_param1_PMU2, V_T_param2_PMU2);
        }
        else
        {
            // ako podaci dolaze u polarnom obliku param1 je modul, param2 je kut
            angle_V_R_PMU1 = calcAngleDegFromPolar(V_R_param2_PMU1);
            angle_V_R_PMU2 = calcAngleDegFromPolar(V_R_param2_PMU2);
            angle_V_S_PMU1 = calcAngleDegFromPolar(V_S_param2_PMU1);
            angle_V_S_PMU2 = calcAngleDegFromPolar(V_S_param2_PMU2);
            angle_V_T_PMU1 = calcAngleDegFromPolar(V_T_param2_PMU1);
            angle_V_T_PMU2 = calcAngleDegFromPolar(V_T_param2_PMU2);
        }
        // odredi razlike za sve parove fazora
        double angle_diff_R_norm = normAngleDeg(angle_V_R_PMU1 - angle_V_R_PMU2);
        double angle_diff_S_norm = normAngleDeg(angle_V_S_PMU1 - angle_V_S_PMU2);
        double angle_diff_T_norm = normAngleDeg(angle_V_T_PMU1 - angle_V_T_PMU2);

        System.out.println("-------Calculations info-------");
        System.out.println(getCurrentLocalDateTimeStamp());
        System.out.println("Angle diff phase R: %05.1f" + angle_diff_R_norm);
        System.out.println("Angle diff phase S: %05.1f" + angle_diff_S_norm);
        System.out.println("Angle diff phase T: %05.1f" + angle_diff_T_norm);
        System.out.println("-------Calculations info end-------");

        double angleLimit = 1.0; // ovo bi trebao biti promjenjivi parametar
        boolean angleDiff_trigger_R = angleDiffCompare(angle_diff_R_norm, angleLimit);
        boolean angleDiff_trigger_S = angleDiffCompare(angle_diff_S_norm, angleLimit);
        boolean angleDiff_trigger_T = angleDiffCompare(angle_diff_T_norm, angleLimit);

        // saljemo byte 0 ako pravilo nije okinulo
        short angleDiffVal = 0;
        if (angleDiff_trigger_R || angleDiff_trigger_S || angleDiff_trigger_T)
        {
            if (angleDiff_trigger_R){
                System.out.println("Phase R angle difference exceeded");
            }
            if (angleDiff_trigger_S){
                System.out.println("Phase S angle difference exceeded");
            }
            if (angleDiff_trigger_T){
                System.out.println("Phase T angle difference exceeded");
            }
            // saljemo byte 0x01 ako je pravilo okinulo
            RandomAccessFile pipe = new RandomAccessFile("IRI2angleDiffRule", "rw");
            // ako je pipe otvoren i pravilo kuteva aktivirano, pisi 1
            short sVal = 1;
            pipe.write((byte) sVal);
            // zatvori pipe kod unistenja klase
            pipe.close();
        }


        return new pmujoinedrule_voltageall(
                pmuJoinedStream.getTimeRounded214(),
                pmuJoinedStream.getPmuId214(),
                pmuJoinedStream.getPhV4R214(),
                pmuJoinedStream.getPhV4J214(),
                pmuJoinedStream.getPhV5R214(),
                pmuJoinedStream.getPhV5J214(),
                pmuJoinedStream.getPhV6R214(),
                pmuJoinedStream.getPhV6J214(),
                pmuJoinedStream.getPmuId218(),
                pmuJoinedStream.getPhV4R218(),
                pmuJoinedStream.getPhV4J218(),
                pmuJoinedStream.getPhV5R218(),
                pmuJoinedStream.getPhV5J218(),
                pmuJoinedStream.getPhV6R218(),
                pmuJoinedStream.getPhV6J218(),
                angle_diff_R_norm,
                angle_diff_S_norm,
                angle_diff_T_norm
        );
    }

//    private SpecificAvroSerde<rawpmu214> raw_pmu214AvroSerde(Properties allProps) {
//        SpecificAvroSerde<rawpmu214> raw_pmu214AvroSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<>();
//        raw_pmu214AvroSerde.configure((Map)allProps, false);
//        return raw_pmu214AvroSerde;
//    }
//
//    private SpecificAvroSerde<rawpmu218> raw_pmu218AvroSerde(Properties allProps) {
//        SpecificAvroSerde<rawpmu218> raw_pmu218AvroSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<>();
//        raw_pmu218AvroSerde.configure((Map)allProps, false);
//        return raw_pmu218AvroSerde;
//    }
//
//    private SpecificAvroSerde<pmujoinstream> pmuJoinAvroSerde(Properties allProps) {
//        SpecificAvroSerde<pmujoinstream> pmuJoinAvroSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<>();
//        pmuJoinAvroSerde.configure((Map)allProps, false);
//        return pmuJoinAvroSerde;
//    }

    private SpecificAvroSerde<pmujoinedrule_voltageall> pmuJoinRuleAvroSerde(Properties allProps) {
        SpecificAvroSerde<pmujoinedrule_voltageall> pmuJoinRuleAvroSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<>();
        pmuJoinRuleAvroSerde.configure((Map)allProps, false);
        return pmuJoinRuleAvroSerde;
    }


    public void createTopics(Properties allProps) {
        AdminClient client = AdminClient.create(allProps);
        List<NewTopic> topics = new ArrayList<>();
//        topics.add(new NewTopic(
//                allProps.getProperty("output.topic.name"),
//                Integer.parseInt(allProps.getProperty("input.topic.partitions")),
//                Short.parseShort(allProps.getProperty("input.topic.replication.factor"))));

        topics.add(new NewTopic(
                allProps.getProperty("rules.topic.name"),
                Integer.parseInt(allProps.getProperty("input.topic.partitions")),
                Short.parseShort(allProps.getProperty("input.topic.replication.factor"))));


        client.createTopics(topics);
        client.close();
    }

    public Properties loadEnvProperties(String fileName) throws IOException {
        Properties allProps = new Properties();
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        allProps.load(input);
        input.close();

        return allProps;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("This program takes one argument: the path to an environment configuration file.");
        }

        JoinWithRule_VoltageAll ts = new JoinWithRule_VoltageAll();
        Properties allProps = ts.loadEnvProperties(args[0]);
        allProps.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        allProps.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, SpecificAvroSerde.class);
        Topology topology = ts.buildTopology(allProps);

        ts.createTopics(allProps);

        final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, allProps);
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        // Attach shutdown handler to catch Control-C.
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread("streams-shutdown-hook") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                streams.close(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
                latch.countDown();
            }
        });

        try {
            streams.start();
            latch.await();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }

    //Helpers and converters

    public static String getCurrentLocalDateTimeStamp() {
        return LocalDateTime.now()
                .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"));
    }
    private static double calcAngleDegFromPolar(double angleRad) {
        return angleRad * 180.0 / Math.PI;
    }
    private static double calcAngleDegFromCartesian(double X, double Y) {
        return Math.atan2(Y, X);
    }
    private static double normAngleDeg(double angle){
        // normira kut na -180 .. +180
        return angle - 360.0 * Math.floor((angle + 180.0) / 360.0);
    }
    private static boolean angleDiffCompare(double angleDiff, double limit){
        return (Math.abs(angleDiff) > limit);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to create some kind of buffer, hold a message for some time, before sending to output topic, you can use [Transformer API](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/Transformer.html).

You can adopt very well known, and described implementation of deduplicating events with Kafka Streams, [here you can find some materials about that](https://blog.softwaremill.com/de-de-de-de-duplicating-events-with-kafka-streams-ed10cfc59fbe).

So in your case, inside `transform(...)` method you just need to put message into some queue/buffer, in order to send it to output topic later. Queue/buffer implementation can be simple `KeyValueStore<K,V>`. You also need to implement `schedule(...)` method on `ProcessorContext`. Inside that method you will find all events ready for trigger, and forward them to output topic. It can be something like that:

```java
public class PLCTriggerTransformer implements Transformer<String, PLCTrigger, KeyValue<String, PLCTrigger>> {

    private KeyValueStore<String, WaitingForTrigger> waitingForTrigger;

    @Override
    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
        this.waitingForTrigger = context.getStateStore("waiting-for-trigger");
        context.schedule(Duration.ofMillis(5), PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME,

            timestamp -> waitingForTrigger.all()
                .forEachRemaining(kV -> {
                    if (kV.value.isReadyForTrigger(timestamp)) {
                        context.forward(kV, kV.value.plcTrigger());
                        waitingForTrigger.delete(kV.key);
                    }
                }));
    }

    @Override
    public KeyValue<String, PLCTrigger> transform(String key, PLCTrigger plcEvent) {
        WaitingForTrigger waitingForTrigger1 = new WaitingForTrigger(System.currentTimeMillis(), plcEvent);
        waitingForTrigger.put(key, waitingForTrigger1);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }

    public record WaitingForTrigger(long arrivalTime, PLCTrigger plcTrigger) {

        boolean isReadyForTrigger(long timestamp) {
            return timestamp - arrivalTime > 25;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Pavel for your valuable answer. But idea is not to  hold messages. If rule is True than PLC is triggered. After that we wait for some fixed time, let's say 5 seconds. During that time messages keep coming only triggering is disabled. After 5 second elapses messages should be allowed to trigger PLC again.

Comment: So during the time when messages are coming and triggering is disabled you just want to skip those messages?

Comment: No, everything continues as usual. Calculations have to continue and messages with calculations continue to be produced in their corresponding topic. Only thing that is different is that in this 5s period PLC triggering should be paused untill next trigger happens. Than triggering will again be paused for same fixed amount of time.